# Can we TWO MMAP on same /dev file

Tags: linux, mmap

1. I have build an character driver in which i am allocating two PAGESIZE buffer using   `dma_alloc_coherent()`
2. Now i am passing the PHYSICAL address of these BUFFER [src_ptr & dest_ptr] to user space using `ioctl()` as `source_offset` and `dest_offset` .
3. In user space this offeset is used as an offset for mmap call.
   So on same /dev file  say /dev/250 i am making TWO MMAP call

   ```
   usr_src_ptr= mmap(0,page_size, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, 
                                  MAP_SHARED,dev_FD,
                                  src_offset );    

   if (usr_src_ptr == MAP_FAILED){
   printf("USR[UPP]:SOURCE MMAP FAiled \n\n");
       close(dev_FD);
       exit(-1);   
   }else{
       printf("USR[UPP]:SOURCE MMAP is %X..\n",usr_src_ptr);
   }

   usr_dest_ptr= mmap(0,page_size, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED,
                                   dev_FD,dest_offset );       
   if (usr_dest_ptr == MAP_FAILED){
        printf("USR[UPP]:DEST MMAP FAiled \n\n");
       close(dev_FD);
       exit(-1);   
   }else{
       printf("USR[UPP]:DEST MMAP is %X..\n",usr_dest_ptr);
   }
   ```
4. I am writing `0x77` in `user_src_ptr` in user space & printing
   `user_src_ptr` in user space and `dest_src_ptr` in KERNEL space .
   I get correct data for both user and kernel space
5. I am writng `0x55` in `dest_ptr` in kernel space & printing `dest_ptr` 
   in kernel space and `usr_dest_ptr` in user space.
   Now for this case I get the correct data e.g. `0X55` in kernel buffer 
   `dest_ptr`, but the user space buffer of destination always
   return `0x77` . i.e the data which I have written into `usr_src_ptr`.

Can any one please let me know if we can do two `mmap()` operations on same file at different OFFSET?

---

Instead of:

```
if ((ret = remap_pfn_range(vma,vma->vm_start,
                          (virt_to_phys((void *)src_ptr) >> PAGE_SHIFT),
                          size,vma->vm_page_prot)) < 0)  return ret;
```

The correct one is:

```
if ((ret = remap_pfn_range(vma,vma->vm_start,
                           vma->vm_pgoff,
                           size,vma->vm_page_prot)) < 0)
```

Thanks BЈовић for your input ....

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as you already found out with your example, you can do mmap() on the same file with different offsets in the same process. The [man page for mmap(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) says nothing about the offset limits (except for it has to be a multiple of the page size as returned by sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE), and off course it shouldn't go beyond the file).

---

There is only [one limit](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/SCSI-Generic-HOWTO/mmap.html) : when mmap()-ing the same file in one process, you have to use the same file ID. You did this in your example, and that's is why it works fine.

Comment: The issue was with :-
if ((ret = remap_pfn_range(vma,vma->vm_start,
(virt_to_phys((void *)src_ptr) >> PAGE_SHIFT),
size,vma->vm_page_prot)) < 0)
{ 
return ret; 
} 

Due to this ir-respective of offset , i was getting mapped to same PHYSICAL address...So now i have two kernel buffer mmap to user space and both behaving individually. i.e two user space buffer mapped to same /dev file at different offset .................

Comment: @Ashish huh?? I do not see `remap_pfn_range` in your question