# Using mmap to map different segments in a file

Tags: c++, linux, mmap

I need to `mmap` the `/dev/mem` address space into my process to access the HW devices. There are several devices with different offsets. The process should be fairly simple with multiple examples available online:

```
  if ((mem_fd_ = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR)) < 0 ) {
    std::cerr << "error opening '/dev/mem' " << strerror(errno);
    return false;
  }

  // Map the kernel memory space
  mmap_addr_ = (uint8_t *)mmap(nullptr, page_size_,
                                PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,
                                MAP_SHARED|MAP_FIXED,
                                mem_fd_,
                                offset_chip_addr_);
  if (mmap_addr_ == MAP_FAILED) {
    std::cerr << "error in mmap: " << strerror(errno);
    return false;
  }
```

But all the examples assume just one call to `mmap` in a process. However, calling `mmap` several times with different values of `offset_chip_addr_` will essentially overwrite the mapped segment with the last call. It is visible from the `/proc/<PID>/maps` file.

Is there a good solution to this problem? Aside from `mmap`'ing a really big chunk of `/dev/mem` once and then just accessing different offsets there.

Comment: Just remove the `MAP_FIXED` flag. If you use it, it tells [`mmap()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) to place the mapping at `nullptr`, and this is what causes your subsequent mappings to be overwritten. Without the flag, the kernel will find a suitable address for the mapping, and will not overwrite any existing mappings.

Comment: @NominalAnimal - actually that is exactly what the OS did. I have 5 calls to `mmap` with different `offset_chip_addr_`. And only last one shows up in `maps` file. There is size and offset value and only the last one is showing.

Comment: @NominalAnimal - `MAP_FIXED` was the problem. I was staring at it and totally missed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use [lseek](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lseek.2.html) to move the current file offset.  Then, the next write() will be to that location.  Alternatively, it may be easier to just mmap multiple different file descriptors to the same file.  See for instance, this question: [Can we TWO MMAP on same /dev file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14581968/can-we-two-mmap-on-same-dev-file) .

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem - just need to remove the `MAP_FIXED` flag from `mmap`:

```
if ((mem_fd_ = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR)) < 0 ) {
    std::cerr << "error opening '/dev/mem' " << strerror(errno);
    return false;
  }

  // Map the kernel memory space
  mmap_addr_ = (uint8_t *)mmap(nullptr, page_size_,
                                PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,
                                MAP_SHARED,
                                mem_fd_,
                                offset_chip_addr_);
  if (mmap_addr_ == MAP_FAILED) {
    std::cerr << "error in mmap: " << strerror(errno);
    return false;
  }
```